# I trying to handle response message and print on alert but its not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

In my code, it sends the SMS to selected phone numbers after sending the message. I want to show the success message in an alert but it's not working.

My code:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
<section class="content">    
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-10">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="box box-primary">
      <div class="box box-default">
          <div class="box-body">
            <form id="getsms" method="post">
              <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 col-lg-5">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Numbers</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" id="number"  dir="" autocomplete="off" readonly value="<?php 
                                //print_r($users);
                                for ($i=0;$i < count($users); $i++) {
                                  echo $users[$i];
                                    echo ",";
                                }
                                 ?>"   />
                   </div>
               </div>
                 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-12">
                       <input type="hidden" name="txt-user-ids" id="txt-user-ids" readonly value="
                                   <?php
                                    for ($i=0;$i < count($user_ids); $i++) {
                                      echo $user_ids[$i];
                                      echo ",";
                                    }
                                    ?>" 
                                    />
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="text_area" rows="10" cols="35" name="getmessage" id="myInput" required></textarea>
                      </div>
                    <div class="box-footer">
                    </div>
              </div>
           </div>
            <button type="button" onclick="getmessageonmobile();" class="btn btn-success col-lg-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-offset-2" name="sendopt">Send</button>
            </form>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
function getmessageonmobile(){
       $.ajax({
              url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin_controllers/CategoryController/bulkSms",
              type: "post",
              data: $('#getsms').serialize(),
              dataType:'json',
        }).done(function( data ) {
            var res=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if(data.status=="success"){
                    alert('Message sucessfully sent ');
                    setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},5000);   
                }else if(res.errors[0].code=="192"){
                  alert(res.errors[0].message);
                }
                else{
                    alert("Try again");
                }    
        });
    }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
function bulkSms(){
        $getsms = $this->input->post('getmessage');
        $number = $this->input->post('number');
        $txtUserIds = $this->input->post('txt-user-ids');
        $myArray = explode(',', $txtUserIds);

       for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($myArray)-1; $i++) {
        $smsData= array(
                        'message'=>$getsms,
                        'sms_user_id'=>$myArray[$i],
             );
      $this->db->insert('historyofmessage',$smsData);

      $string_version=array();
      $string_version = implode(', ', (array)$number);
      $apiKey = urlencode('rTQHR7zsvVeKU79sojb6grGRAavnKW');
      $numbers = array($string_version);
      $sender = urlencode('TXTLCL');
      $unicode=1;
      $message = rawurlencode($getsms);

    $numbers = implode(',', $numbers);

    $data = array('apikey' => $apiKey, 'numbers' => $numbers, "sender" => $sender, "message" => $message,"unicode"=>$unicode);

    $ch = curl_init('https://api.textlocal.in/send/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo json_encode($response);
 }
}
```

Bellow image you can see the response in the console after sending the message.
[image]

In the image, I select two different numbers and send a message just want to handle the response and show in the alert if the message sends or message not send.

Comment: can you show the response json?

Comment: Kindly donot post images of the code , instead copy paste it so that we can debug it easily.

Comment: `Response{"warnings":[{"code":3,"message":"Invalid number"}],"balance":80,"batch_id":960128131,"cost":1,"num_messages":1,"message":{"num_parts":1,"sender":"TXTLCL","content":"@U006A0068006B006A"},"receipt_url":"","custom":"","messages":[{"id":"11326265607","recipient":919999999999}],"status":"success"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this success function -

```
  success:function(data){
     var myJson = JSON.parse(data);
     if(myJson.status == "success"){
              alert('Message sucessfully sent ');
              setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},5000);   
       }else if(myJson.warnings[0].code =="192"){
              console.log(myJson.warnings[0].message);
       }else{
              alert("Try again");
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try writing it in a success function and print the error response in the console window of browser -

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin_controllers/CategoryController/bulkSms",
     type: "post",
     dataType:'json',
     data: $('#getsms').serialize(),
     success:function(data){
     if(data.status=="success"){
              alert('Message sucessfully sent ');
              setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},5000);   
       }else if(data.errors[0].code=="192"){
              console.log(data.errors[0].message);
       }else{
              alert("Try again");
       }    
   });
```

Comment: `sendMessagePage:472 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: `}else if(data.errors[0].code=="192"){` in this line

Comment: Can you print the "data" in console? console.log(data); and check how the json response is coming.

Comment: `{"warnings":[{"code":3,"message":"Invalid number"}],"balance":76,"batch_id":960191231,"cost":1,"num_messages":1,"message":{"num_parts":1,"sender":"TXTLCL","content":"@U0063006800650063006B002000740068006500200063006F006E0073006F006C0065"},"receipt_url":"","custom":"","messages":[{"id":"11326427431","recipient":91845988815}],"status":"success"}`

Answer (score 0):

hi can i see the return line from controller that you are sending back

Comment: `Response{"warnings":[{"code":3,"message":"Invalid number"}],"balance":80,"batch_id":960128131,"cost":1,"num_messages":1,"message":{"num_parts":1,"sender":"TXTLCL","content":"@U006A0068006B006A"},"receipt_url":"","custom":"","messages":[{"id":"11326265607","recipient":919999999999}],"status":"success"}` this is the response I am geting from controller.

Comment: you are returning value in json form from controller